# Incorrect number of columns displayed in jQuery masonry page

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am trying to get the masonry plugin working with a tumblr theme. I need it to have 4 columns but for some reason it is only displaying 2.

http://penguinenglishlibrary.tumblr.com/

Can anyone help please?

I would create a jsfiddle but time is really against me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the container is 940px. Each of your book elements are 235+10=245px wide. 245X4 = 980px.

The container just isn't wide enough due to the margins.

What surprises me is that it's not putting 3 books per row. I don't know the Masonry API or your settings in order to guess why it might behave that way, though.

Comment: I just tried that and it seems to work before masonry kicks in and moves everything into 2 cols, any ideas? Thanks a bunch btw

Comment: Oh isn't that interesting...? Weird. No, I'm at a loss right now. I can see them being "mason'd" and then as you say, moving to 2 columns. If you're good with debuggers, put break points along the way to see which of your layout management functions is causing it to go to 2. I'll have a quick look but I'm indisposed for much of an investigation. Sorry!

Comment: Something you're doing must be working; I can see them all mason'd now!